# standard rectangle class

Tags: c++

I have a project that has a GUI (written in QT) and a command-line version.  I made use of the rectangle class included in QT: [QRect](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qrectf.html).  I would like to break the command-line version's dependency on QT, so I need a drop-in rectangle class that supports intersection and union.  I could write one, but I'd prefer including one if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh Lord, why do you lose sleep over this?  That extra hundred of bytes of virtual memory you'll consume is something *I* won't notice.  Make it a real question, show us how to nice it.

Comment: Qt is a rather heavy dependency for something that only need a rectangle class. And what does "nicing it" mean anyways...

Comment: Writing intersect and union for rectangles is a standard interview question I ask.  Write your own and become a better person for it.

Comment: You don't need all of Qt just for `QRect`. Just `QtCore`. Having said that a rectangle class is not difficult to write...

Comment: hahaha.  I really don't agree that it would "make me a better person."  Look at all of those methods:  What you're seeing is a day of my life spent indoors versus a day spent outside after typing "#include <...>".

Comment: @Neil: Wait, there's something else other than indoor? D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to find one to include, it's probably part of another dependency. So your best bet is to try to write your own. Now is a good time to practice making a template class. :)

```
template <typename T>
struct point
{
    // or maybe you'd prefer to make these private
    T x;
    T y;
};

template <typename T>
struct rectangle
{
public:
    typedef point<T> point_type;

    bool contains(const point_type& pPoint)
    {
        return !(pPoint.x < topleft.x) && (pPoint.x < bottomright.x) && 
                !(pPoint.y < topleft.y) && (pPoint.y < bottomright.y);
    }

    T width(void) const
    {
        return bottomright.x - topleft.x;
    }

    // and more stuff

    // or maybe you'd prefer to make these private, nor
    // is this the only way to represent a rectangle.
    point_type topleft;
    point_type bottomright;
};
```

Sorry it's not the answer you're expecting.

---

Just about your design, I hope you're not taking your GUI version, performing a copy, then modifying it into a console version. Better would be to make a library; then GUI versus console is merely a matter of presentation.

Comment: That's fine, thanks for starting it off (nice attention to boundary cases by the way.)

Anyway, it was worth a shot asking.  Smaller things have made it into boost.  Hopefully this gets put in too....